# Is it safe to remove MCInitContentProvider in our AndroidManifest?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, android, mobilepush-android

Just a question. Is it possible to remove the MCInitContentProvider in our AndroidManifest? Not have it registered when compiling the apk. It seems like the point of this content provider is to expose the context for the SDK. But during initialization, I've always passed in my own context. I can't determine the usage since the marketingcloud android sdk is obfuscated.

```
    <provider
    android:name="com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MCInitContentProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.com.salesforce.marketingcloud.initprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    tools:node="remove" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intention is not to expose `Context` to the SDK and it is not okay to remove this.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Though I think my team is passing the context to the SDK during the init function. is there MCInitContentProvider usages in the sdk other than registering in the AndroidManifest?

Comment: My security team flagged the content provider as a potential issue due to content provider being leaked to malicious third party apps (though it was patched 2 years ago, some devices might not be patched yet). I know this content provider is a very bare bones. I wonder if removing this content provider affect the sdk in any way.

Comment: Please see my answer.  Do not remove the `Content Provider`.